# Problems using integrate while writing a likelihood function

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a likelihood function for a distribution which is defined by an integration. I'm using the integrate() function, but when I try to use this in the rest of the function I get the error:

"Error in B(alpha + i, beta + 6 - i)/B(alpha, beta) : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

The value of the integration is for example "9.501501 with absolute error < 0.00078". I've tried to use trunc() but this doesn't help either. I'm relatively new to R, so is there a known solution to this? Any help would be appreciated!

```
B <- function(a,b){ 
   integrand <- function(t){(t^(a-1))*((1-t)^(b-1))} 
   integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=1) 
} 
betalik <- function(alpha,beta){ 
    likelihood <- 0 Z <- c(37,22,25,29,34,49) 
    for(i in 1:6) 
       likelihood <- likelihood + 
         Z[i]*log((B(alpha+i,beta+6-i))/B(alpha,beta)) 
    return(likelihood)
```

}

Dorian,

Comment: You haven't given us enough information.  At the very least with a question like this you should post the code for what gave you an error.

Comment: No problem, here is the code:

B <- function(a,b){
  integrand <- function(t){(t^(a-1))*((1-t)^(b-1))}
  integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=1)
}

betalik <- function(alpha,beta){
  likelihood <- 0
  Z <- c(37,22,25,29,34,49)
  for(i in 1:6) likelihood <- likelihood + Z[i]*log((B(alpha+i,beta+6-i))/B(alpha,beta))
  return(likelihood)
}

Comment: Hmmm, the tyepsetting isn't quite cooperating...

Comment: You should really edit that into your question instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: Also - there is a built in function for the beta function (try `beta`) and there is already a built in function for the beta density (try `dbeta`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on the comments and answers above ...

Here are your original functions, formatted more nicely, integrating @Fhnuzoag's comment about extracting the `$value` component from the `integrate()` result:

```
B <- function(a,b){
    integrand <- function(t){(t^(a-1))*((1-t)^(b-1))}
    integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=1)$value
}
betalik <- function(alpha,beta){
    likelihood <- 0
    Z <- c(37,22,25,29,34,49)
    for(i in 1:6) likelihood <- likelihood +
        Z[i]*log((B(alpha+i,beta+6-i))/B(alpha,beta))
    return(likelihood)
}
```

Here we check @dason's comment that your `B` function is equivalent to R's built-in `beta` function (but R's function is certainly faster and very probably more accurate):

```
all.equal(B(1.1,2.7),beta(1.1,2.7))  ## TRUE
```

I prefer to specify the 'data' separately:

```
Z <- c(37,22,25,29,34,49)
```

A new version of the likelihood function that uses the built-in `lbeta` (log-beta) function, and is vectorized:

```
blik2 <- function(alpha,beta,Z) {
    index <- 1:6
    sum(Z*(lbeta(alpha+index,beta+6-index)-lbeta(alpha,beta)))
}

all.equal(blik2(1.1,2.7,Z),betalik(1.1,2.7))
## small difference, blik2 is *probably* more
##   accurate ... "Mean relative difference: 6.406495e-08"
```

(It might be good to generalize this a bit further and replace the values of `6` in the code with `length(Z)` ...)

Comment: Thank you for the insightful feedback everyone. Good to know how things work if you use integrate(), but lbeta was enough for what I wanted to do. Got some other little bugs to work through with optim(), but in general things are working!

Comment: OK; if you feel your question has been answered you can accept one answer or the other.  Depending on what you're doing with your likelihood estimation, you may find either the `mle` function from the `stats4` package or the `mle2` function from `bbmle` useful (there's also a `maxLik` package ...)  Just as a warning, most of these packages require you to specify the *negative* log-likelihood ...

Answer (score 4):

Using the integrate example from `?integrate`....

```
integrate(dnorm, -1.96, 1.96)
# 0.9500042 with absolute error < 1e-11
```

What's actually going on here? Well, the integrate function creates an "integrate" class S3 object, which is basically a list with a number of fields, and then applies `print()` to it , executing in turn `print.integrate()`. The output of the function isn't *actually* the string "0.9500042 with absolute error < 1e-11", it's merely displayed that way.

To get at what the R object created by `integrate()` actually is, do

```
obj = integrate(dnorm, -1.96, 1.96)
str(obj)
# List of 5
# $ value       : num 0.95
# $ abs.error   : num 1.05e-11
# $ subdivisions: int 1
# $ message     : chr "OK"
# $ call        : language integrate(f = dnorm, lower = -1.96, upper = 1.96)
# - attr(*, "class")= chr "integrate"
```

So, if you just want the value of the integral, then you would have to extract the `value` field of the list created by that function, for your computation. E.g.

```
10*integrate(dnorm, -1.96, 1.96)$value
# [1] 9.500042
```